# NullPointerException error i.e. AndroidDriver not gets initialized for the second test class as It's working fine for the first test class

Tags: selenium, automation, nullpointerexception, appium-android, testng-eclipse

**This is My setup class:**

public class SetupClass {

```
//AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> d;
public Properties prop =null;
public File file;
public FileInputStream fis;

@Parameters(value ="Android")
@BeforeSuite
public void setup(String Android) throws IOException, Exception{
    LoadPropertiesFile();
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    /*caps.setCapability("plateformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");*/
    if (Android.equalsIgnoreCase("Moto_g4_Plus")) {
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.0");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "ZY223WZSQ9");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Moto G4 Plus");
    }
    caps.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\amarjeet.sharma\\eclipse-workspace\\com.asm.app\\src\\test\\resources\\app\\asmVisit.apk");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sumasoft.net.asmscheduler");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "md5f32326382a711c73d2de951d70f3bd5e.MainActivity");
    caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        //driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, caps);
        d = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, caps);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Cause is:" +e.getCause());
        System.out.println("Message is:" +e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void LoadPropertiesFile() throws IOException {       
    prop=new Properties();      
    file =new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources/config.properties");     
    fis=new FileInputStream(file);
    prop.load(fis);     
    //System.out.println(prop.getProperty("userId"));
}

//@AfterTest
public void TearDown() throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Quit");
    d.quit();
}
```

}

**This is My LoginTest**

public class LoginTest extends SetupClass{

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void login() throws Exception {
    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(d);
    //System.out.println(prop.getProperty("userId"));
    lp.userName(prop.getProperty("userId"));
    Thread.sleep(500);
    lp.password(prop.getProperty("Passwd"));
    Thread.sleep(500);
    lp.loginButton();           
}
```

}

**And this is my create new journey class**

public class AddJourneyTest extends SetupClass{

```
@Test(priority=2)
public void AddNewJourney() throws Exception {

    AddjourneyPage addobj = new AddjourneyPage(d);
    addobj.ClicktoAdd();
    addobj.SelectFromToDate();
    addobj.SelectState();
    addobj.SelectCity();
    addobj.ClickonSubmit();
}
```

}

**I am getting NullPointerException for AddJourney class**
*I think when I run it as TestNG then the driver gets initiated for the LoginTest and holds the control. So that AddJourney class does not get driver initiated and hence getting NullPointerException.*
I am using Appium Server, **Java + Selenium + TestNG** for the Android Application automation on Windows system with physical android device.
Maybe I am wrong. But I am not getting solution over it. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace of your exception?

Comment: AddNewJourney java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:103)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:92)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:79)
 at pages.AddjourneyPage.<init>(AddjourneyPage.java:25)
 at tests.AddJourneyTest.AddNewJourney(AddJourneyTest.java:11)
 at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
... Removed 27 stack frames

Comment: Can you also show `AddjourneyPage`. Also please do not put code or exceptions in comment. Rather update your question accordingly.

Comment: The object of AddJourneyPage is created in AddJourneyTest. I have just initiated the page factory as below for both class *public AddjourneyPage(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> d){
  this.d= d;
  System.out.println("Test1:="+d);
  PageFactory.initElements(d, this.d);  
 }*

Comment: LoginTest call the LoginPage and LoginTest extends SetupClass. Similarly, AddJourneyTest calls the AddJourneyPage and AddJourneyTest also extends SetupClass. In SetupClass setup method is annotated as **@BeforeSuit** and rest are present in the above code. So I am not getting that where did I mistake.